# Vector addition exercise: Plane and Wind

Tags: plane-geometry

I sit since 2 days on it and can't solce it:

A plane flies with the speed of vF=240 km/h in direction of north. It flies into a storm from north east with the wind speed of v=90 km/h.
What's the actual speed of the plane above the ground and how big is the angle deviaton between actual course and the heading?

Since vectorial addition usually has 3 variables, I needed a couple of hours to figuring out how it could be solved, so I tried:
√(vF^2+v^2) for plane speed, but it doesn't make any sense that it goes faster. With it the angle deviation would be also false.

Comment: refer https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for proper formatting

Comment: If you want the vectors to have three variables, use the first coordinate for east, the second for north, and set the third coordinate always to zero.

Comment: That still doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Then the complaint about "3 variables" was not really relevant, was it? Have you done vector sums before? What are the vectors in this problem, and how do they need to be added to get an answer?

Comment: Hint: you have computed the correct speed over the ground if the wind were coming from the east. But the problem says the wind comes from the northeast.

Comment: Break the North-East wind into two components - one in the north direction and the east direction. The north component seems to reduce the speed and the east divert it.